# How can I add a start and stop button to this please?

Tags: javascript, button, slideshow

I am unsure on how I would add buttons to this please help I need it to stop and start the slide show thanks I have been unable to get it working for around two hours I have only just started coding and this is the only real thing I am stuck on, thanks again.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var slideimages = new Array() 
slideimages[0] = new Image() 
slideimages[0].src = "https://www.missionmanager.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/number-1-199440.jpg" 
slideimages[1] = new Image()
slideimages[1].src = "https://www.missionmanager.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/red-number-2.jpg"
slideimages[2] = new Image()
slideimages[2].src = "https://www.missionmanager.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/red-number-3.jpg"

</script>
</head>
<body>
<img src="" id="slide" width="150" height="260" />

<script type="text/javascript">

var step=0

function slideit(){


 document.getElementById('slide').src = slideimages[step].src
 if (step<2)
  step++
 else
  step=0

 setTimeout("slideit()",2500)
}

slideit()

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

Highlights of my changes

1. Added 2 buttons in HTML for starting and stopping the slide show
2. Added a start() function that calls your slideit() function when the start button is clicked instead of being called automatically
3. Added a variable myTimer to keep the timer instance
4. Added a stop() function that clears the timer when the stop button is clicked

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var slideimages = new Array()
     slideimages[0] = new Image()
     slideimages[0].src = "https://www.missionmanager.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/number-1-199440.jpg"
    slideimages[1] = new Image()
     slideimages[1].src = "https://www.missionmanager.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/red-number-2.jpg"
    slideimages[2] = new Image()
     slideimages[2].src = "https://www.missionmanager.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/red-number-3.jpg"
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="" id="slide" width="150" height="260" />
  <button onclick="start()">Start</button>
  <button onclick="stop()">Stop</button>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    var step = 0;
    var myTimer = null;

    function slideit() {


      document.getElementById('slide').src = slideimages[step].src
      if (step < 2)
        step++
        else
          step = 0

      myTimer = setTimeout("slideit()", 2500)
    }

    function start() {
      slideit();
    }

    function stop() {
      if (myTimer != null)
        clearTimeout(myTimer);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```